# MPMoviePlayerController notification question

Tags: iphone, ios4, notifications, media-player, avfoundation

Good Evening Fellas!
Is it possible for me to get a notification from an MPMoviePlayerController while it is playing a video. I mean, if i am able to get it every second, millisecond etc. 
I have an indicator for the video current playback time that i want it updated continuously.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is going to be to set up a repeating timer yourself, and use that to update your display.  e.g.:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```